# React Native - AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding algorithm to encrypt with the key and string

Tags: android, react-native

I am working in React Native app, I need to encrypt the data using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding algorithm in my React Native app. I did this in my Android app too and it's working like a charm but in React Native app, not giving the same result.

#### Android side code (working code)

```
private String encodeParameters(String keyFrom, String param) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyFrom.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(param.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return encryptedValue;
}
```

#### React Native code (not working)

```
var data = "some plain text";
var key = "1234567891234567";
var iv = "1234567891234567";
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
});
var final = base64.encode(encrypted)
console.log('encrypted: ' + final) ;
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,key,{iv:iv,padding:CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding});
console.log('decrypted: '+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

As, this code encrypt the data but I need the same functionality/same encryption pattern like in Android.

Comment: Sir, any update on this issue? Did you get your answer? Also, I would like to the exact error that you were facing. Thanks!

Comment: Hai sir, have you got any solution regarding this.